# Why are static analysis tools missing this seemingly obvious case?

Tags: cppcheck, clang-static-analyzer

I have a very simple C program with a potential buffer overflow using `strcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void buffer_overflow(char* dst, const char* src)
{
        strcpy(dst, src);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        if(argc == 2)
        {
                char buffer[16] = {0};
                buffer_overflow(buffer, argv[1]);
                printf("[%d]: %s", (int)strlen(buffer), buffer);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Neither clang static analyzer (using `scan-build gcc -O0 -g3 -gdwarf-2`) nor cppcheck (using `cppcheck --enable=warning,style`) find this as an issue.

Am I just asking too much from my static analysis tools?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, from a static analysis point of view, this program is 100% fine? It's the _dynamic_ parameters that are troublesome, but how is static analysis supposed to foresee what you will enter? Assume you did it "properly" and first called `strlen`, then reserved memory. What if I call your program with an argument that's two gigabytes long?

Comment: `cppcheck` finds the `strcpy()` as problematic if I don't hide it away in the {{buffer_overflow()}} question. Clang static analyzer _specifically_ has an analyzer for the `strcpy` API.

Comment: @Damon: the point of a static analysis is to tell you that there is a circumstance in which your application can go wrong.  Clearly that can happen with large sizes of argv[1], so in theory the analyzers could detect this.  (After all, you can detect it, why can't an algorithm?)

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the quality of "your" static analysis tools.

Here's a dynamic analysis tool, [CheckPointer](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety?site=StackOverflow), from my company that finds the problem(s) with your code (which I tested as "buggy.c"):

```
C:\DMS\Domains\C\GCC4\Tools\CheckPointer\Example>runexample
RunExample.cmd 1.2: Batch file to execute C CheckPointer example
Copyright (C) 2011-2016 Semantic Designs; All Rights Reserved
c:\DMS\Domains\C\GCC4\Tools\CheckPointer\Example\Source\buggy.c
*** Instrument source code for memory access checking
Copyright (C) 2011 Semantic Designs; All Rights Reserved
C~GCC4 CheckPointer Version 1.2.1001
Copyright (C) 2011-2016 Semantic Designs, Inc; All Rights Reserved; SD Confidential
Powered by DMS (R) Software Reengineering Toolkit
*** Unregistered CheckPointer Version 1.2
*** Operating with evaluation limits.
Parsing source file "C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example/Source/buggy.c" using encoding CP-1252 +CRLF $^J $^M $^e -1 +8 ...
Writing target file "C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example/Target/buggy.c" using encoding CP-1252 +CRLF $^J $^M $^e -1 +8 ...
*** Compiling sources with memory access checking code
gcc.exe -I"c:\DMS\Domains\C\GCC4\Tools\CheckPointer" -I.\Target -obuggy.exe Target\buggy.c ...


C:\DMS\Domains\C\GCC4\Tools\CheckPointer\Example\Source>C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example\buggy.exe foo
[3]: foo

C:\DMS\Domains\C\GCC4\Tools\CheckPointer\Example\Source>C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example\buggy.exe 0123456789ABCDE
[15]: 0123456789ABCDE

C:\DMS\Domains\C\GCC4\Tools\CheckPointer\Example\Source>C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example\buggy.exe 0123456789ABCDEF
*** Error: CWE-119: Improper Restriction of Operations within the Bounds of a Memory Buffer
       Dereference of pointer is out of bounds.
  in wrapper function: strcpy
called in function: buffer_overflow, line: 6, file: C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example/Source/buggy.c
called in function: main, line: 14, file: C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example/Source/buggy.c
*** Error: CWE-119: Improper Restriction of Operations within the Bounds of a Memory Buffer
       Dereference of pointer is out of bounds.
  in wrapper function: strlen
called in function: main, line: 15, file: C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example/Source/buggy.c
*** Error: CWE-119: Improper Restriction of Operations within the Bounds of a Memory Buffer
       Dereference of pointer is out of bounds.
  in wrapper function: printf
called in function: main, line: 15, file: C:/Users/idbaxter/AppData/Local/Temp/DMS/Domains/C/GCC4/Tools/CheckPointer/Example/Source/buggy.c
[16]: 0123456789ABCDEF
C:\DMS\Domains\C\GCC4\Tools\CheckPointer\Example\Source>
```

Comment: is this from "Semantic Designs"?  Does it support C++ as well?

Comment: Yes, this is from Semantic Designs.  When I say things like this I tend to get burned by SO commercial product haters.    No, we don't have one for C++.  Yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly open-ended question that doesn't have a right answer.  But as someone who has worked on several static analyzers, I'll bite and briefly explain what's hard about this example.

### Problem 1: False positives

You and I know that `argv[1]` could be an arbitrarily long string.  (In part that knowledge is derived from the context of being a Stack Overflow question, in which code is usually presented absent any context or a-prior assumptions.)  But if a static analyzer reported every `strcpy` where the source string was not known (by the static analyzer!) to have a bounded length, it would in practice report a very large number of what most developers would consider false positives (FPs): incorrect reports that they don't want to see.

That's because there a very large number of cases where `strcpy` is used correctly, but the reason it is correct is beyond the reasoning capacity of the analyzer, and might not even be present in the source code at all (e.g., "program X is only ever invoked by program Y, which never passes arguments longer than 80 characters").  In comparison, only a very small fraction of `strcpy` calls (with arguments the analyzer can't bound) are wrong.  Let's be generous and say 10% of them are wrong--that's still a 90% FP rate if we report them all, far beyond what most developers will tolerate.

When a tool reports too many FPs, most developers quickly stop using them, at which point it's providing *no value*.  Consequently, most static analyses choose to limit what they report to cases where the tool is fairly confident, at least by default.

### Problem 2: Interprocedural analysis

Even for a tool that wants to report this (as you say Cppcheck does, when the `strcpy` is directly in `main`), the second problem is understanding what `buffer_overflow` does.  It is impractical for a static analyzer to simply "inline" the contents of callees into callers arbitrarily deeply because the resulting AST would be enormous and the number of paths astronomical.  Consequently, analyzers generally *summarize* callee behavior.  The exact form of those summaries, and the algorithms that compute them, are the subject of active academic research and closely guarded trade secrets.

The behavior of `strcpy` is actually fairly complex compared to what a typical function summary can express.  There is a size involved, but that size is derived by examining the *contents* of the data one of the pointers points at, specifically the location of the *first NUL byte*.  Then that size affects what happens to the things *pointed at* by both arguments.  That's a lot to encode in a summary in a general and scalable way, so most tools don't.  As a result, the tool has only a very crude understanding of what `buffer_overflow` does, typically too crude to allow it to confidently report a defect here.